# Python 2.7.2 Ubuntu + Django 1.4; deepcopy recursion error when ".objects.get(foo=unicodestr)"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting a strange error on a obviously simple task.

I want to query a sqlite DB with an unicode string and with following model:

```
from django.db import models

class Uebersetzung(models.Model):
    artikel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    deutsch = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    turk    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    added   = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

The query takes place in a "stand alone script" i am only using django's models and apis, my query looks like this:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'turk.settings'
from turk.parse.models import *
...

   # each is a tuple of eg. (u'das', u'Haus', u'bina')
   try:
        Uebersetzung.objects.get(artikel=each[0],deutsch=each[1],turk=each[2])
    except Uebersetzung.DoesNotExist:
        tr =  Uebersetzung(artikel=each[0],deutsch=each[1],turk=each[2])
        tr.save()
        print "Adding \'%s %s -> %s\' to Uebersetzung" % (each[0],each[1],each[2])
```

Im getting an error like this:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just a hint: why don't you use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create)?

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Since i use BeautifulSoup i have to cast it to unicode:

```
try:
    Uebersetzung.objects.get(artikel=unicode(each[0]),deutsch=unicode(each[1]),turk=unicode(each[2]))
```

see: [python - Problem storing Unicode character to MySQL with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102465/python-problem-storing-unicode-character-to-mysql-with-django)

Comment: You should [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: can't have to wait until tomorrow. Then i will!