# storing Unicode subclasses to MySQL with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode

I got a problem with saving Unicode chars in MySQL.

```
    Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
    Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)

    Exception Location: /home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in string_literal, line 204
    Python Executable:  /home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.11
```

Error is rasing in MySQL library:

```
    def _get_string_literal():
        def string_literal(obj, dummy=None):
            # try:
            return db.string_literal(obj) ...
            # except UnicodeEncodeError:
            #    return db.string_literal(unicode(obj).encode("utf-8"))
        return string_literal
```

Variable:

```
obj = u'temp/files_widget/2016-05-31-15-00/1/Sn\xedmek obrazovky po\u0159\xedzen\xfd 2016-05-23 10-34-59.png'
```

I think that the problem is related to this issue:
[python - Problem storing Unicode character to MySQL with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102465/python-problem-storing-unicode-character-to-mysql-with-django)

My "obj" variable is not pure Unicode but it is ImagePath class instance.

```
class ImagePaths(unicode):
    item_class = ImagePath
```

The problem is that I don't know which method shoud be implemented to fix the problem.

Note:
My fix is commented in the code above. But it is not much clean solution. It is directly written in MySQL library.

## Update #1:

Full traceback:

```
        /home/truhlik/Dropbox/web/reality/permissions/models.py in save
        super(CustomModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save_base
            updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in _save_table
                                      forced_update) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in _do_update
        return filtered._update(values) > 0 ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _update
        return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
        cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
            cursor.execute(sql, params) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
            return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute
            return self.cursor.execute(query, args) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute
                query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in literal
        return self.escape(o, self.encoders) ...

/home/truhlik/.virtualenvs/reality/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in string_literal
                return db.string_literal(obj)
```

Using this connection settings:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'reality_devel',
    'USER': 'reality_devel',
    'HOST': 'mail.it-poradce.cz',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'charset': 'utf8',
        'use_unicode': True,
    }
}
```

MySQL database is configured `COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`

Found couple issues reported directly to Django and MySQL, which are maybe related to my issue.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79993
and
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22377
But I am not sure.

## Update #2:

I am trying to save a path to images, using this Field.

```
images = files_widget.ImagesField(_(u'Obrázky'), blank=True, null=True, help_text=HELP_TEXT_IMAGES)
```

The Field is Implemented this way:

```
class FilesField(models.TextField):
    description = _("Files")
    attr_class = controllers.FilePaths

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.accept = kwargs.pop('accept', None)
        super(FilesField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        super(FilesField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        receiver(post_save, sender=cls)(manage_files_on_disk)
        setattr(cls, self.name, controllers.FilesDescriptor(self))

    def save_form_data(self, instance, data):
        save_all_data(self, instance, data)
        super(FilesField, self).save_form_data(instance, data)

    def formfield(self, default_widget=None, **kwargs):
        if not default_widget:
            default_widget = FilesWidget(field=self, accept=self.accept)
        defaults = formfield_defaults(self, default_widget, **kwargs)
        return super(FilesField, self).formfield(**defaults)

class ImagesField(FilesField):
    description = _("Images")
    attr_class = controllers.ImagePaths

    def formfield(self, default_widget=None, **kwargs):
        if not default_widget:
            default_widget = ImagesWidget(field=self, accept=self.accept)
        defaults = formfield_defaults(self, default_widget, **kwargs)
        return super(ImagesField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

It is using this app: django-files-widget ... so If you will need to see more code, then you can check it on GitHub.
*Sorry, can't post full URL.*

Trying to find where should I...

> properly convert to unicode

but don't figure it out.

## Update #3:

Add result of: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`

```
character_set_client - utf8mb4
character_set_connection - utf8mb4
character_set_database - utf8
character_set_filesystem - binary
character_set_results - utf8mb4
character_set_server - latin1
character_set_system - utf8
character_sets_dir - /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending a `unicode` object to the library code where it expects to receive a `str` object. There is not much context to go by from the code you posted (try posting the entire traceback) but handling the exception by modifying the MySQLdb library is not the proper way to do it. You should handle it in the client code that calls the library. Find the point in your traceback which comes before the line that raises the exception and then move your `try: except:` block there.

Among other things that can cause this is that your `Connection` object is being created with `use_unicode = False`.

**EDIT:** Some sample code below. Since you did not post the code for your `CustomClass` I wrote the following simple class which works just fine.

in models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CustomClass(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I set up my database with the same `OPTIONS` you have. Then testing from shell:

```
>>> c = CustomClass()
>>> c.path = u'temp/files_widget/2016-05-31-15-00/1/Sn\xedmek obrazovky po\u0159\xedzen\xfd 2016-05-23 10-34-59.png'
>>> c.save()
>>>
```

Maybe you are doing something non-standard somewhere in your code which is causing the `UnicodeEncodeError`. Maybe in your custom `save()` method or some other client code before that. Maybe you are using a custom `Field` subclass which does not properly convert to unicode.

Comment: It looks like you have a misconfiguration though I cannot pinpoint where exactly. The links in your update refer to `UnicodeDecodeError` not `UnicodeEncodeError` which is what you are getting. The exception you are getting comes from code that tries to convert a `unicode` object into a `str` object. Try `str(u'temp/files_widget/2016-05-31-15-00/1/Sn\xedmek obrazovky po\u0159\xedzen\xfd 2016-05-23 10-34-59.png')` to see what I mean.

Comment: _Maybe you are using a custom Field subclass which does not properly convert to unicode._ ... this probably will be the issue. I added my code with CustomField implementation.

Comment: You will also want to look at how the value for that field is being assigned. Did you try assigning manually and then saving the model using Django shell as I did above? The two classes you posted above does not seem to do anything special with its value which would cause this error. So it's clearly something else you are doing that's causing all this.

Comment: Try manuall and the error is same: 
>>> `e.images
u''
>>> e.images = u'temp/files_widget/2016-05-31-15-00/1/Sn\xedmek obrazovky po\u0159\xedzen\xfd 2016-05-23 10-34-59.png'
>>> e.save()
>>> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 0):

Hex `ed` is not Unicode, nor is it utf8.  Perhaps you were expecting `í`?  That is what latin1 encodes as `ed`.

Where did `ed` come from?  Either change it to encode things in utf8 or declare that you are using latin1, not utf8.

Python tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python
Django tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages

Comment: Thx for advice. The string comes from FILE name which is uploaded to Django via Form. So I suppose that it should already be utf8. If not, where should I put the encode to utf8 (in form init, or model save)?
The second point from me... if I use the exactly same string for the instance.name the it is correctly saved to DB. 
So I still suppose that the problem will be in CustomField class and their implementation.

Comment: Is `Obrázky` the name of a table column?  Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`.  One of those probably controls how to treat column (etc) names.  Also, do you have documentation on what `_(u'...')` does?  It needs to generate utf8, not unicode, not html entities.

Comment: I have updated my questing with results of the query.